# Python 2 assertItemsEqual incorrect result

Tags: python, python-unittest

I ran into an interesting situation with the `unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual` function under Python 2; posting my findings here for posterity.

The following unit test breaks under Python 2 when it should succeed:

```
import unittest

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{})'.format(self.a, self.b)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.a, self.b) < (other.a, other.b)

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo_eq(self):
        self.assertEqual(sorted([Foo()]), sorted([Foo()]))
        self.assertItemsEqual([Foo()], [Foo()])

unittest.main()
```

Here is the output:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_foo_eq (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tsanders/scripts/one_offs/test_unittest_assert_items_equal2.py", line 17, in test_foo_eq
    self.assertItemsEqual([Foo()], [Foo()])
AssertionError: Element counts were not equal:
First has 1, Second has 0:  (1,2)
First has 0, Second has 1:  (1,2)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

This is pretty confusing since the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual) state:

> It [`assertItemsEqual`] is the equivalent of `assertEqual(sorted(expected), sorted(actual))` but it works with sequences of unhashable objects as well.

The same test passes under Python 3 (after swapping `self.assertItemsEqual` for `self.assertCountEqual`, since the name has changed).

EDIT: After posting this question, I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10455538/3282436) other question that covers the situation where neither `__eq__` nor `__hash__` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the test passing under both Python 2 and 3, I had to add the line `__hash__ = None` to `Foo`.

The `assertItemsEqual`/`assertCountEqual` function takes different code paths depending on whether or not the items in each list are hashable.  And according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> If a class does not define a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either; if it defines `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable in hashed collections.

With that in mind, Python 2 and 3 have different behavior with regard to `__hash__` when `__eq__` is defined:

- In Python 2, defining `__eq__` does not affect the default-provided `__hash__`, but trying to use the item in a hashed container results in implementation-defined behavior (e.g. keys may be duplicated because they have different hashes, even if `__eq__` would return `True`).
- In Python 3, defining `__eq__` sets `__hash__` to `None`.

As of Python 2.6, `__hash__` can be explicitly set to `None` to make a class unhashable.  In my case, this was *required* to get `assertItemsEqual` to use the correct comparison algorithm that relies on `__eq__` instead of `__hash__`.